# How to append a document to a 2nd level embedded model list document in Django and mongoengine

Tags: pymongo, django-nonrel

I'm currently facing some issues trying to add a embedded model object into a list which is also inside a embedded model list.
I'm using Django nonrel and mongoengine with djangotoolbox.
So, this is my mongo collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("517fe872e138235e2cae9e8c"),
"campaigns" : [
    {
        "payout" : 0.7,
        "landing_page" : [ ],
        "name" : "A prueba de todo",
        "rotate_urls" : null,
        "_module" : "setup.models",
        "_model" : "Campaigns",
        "cloaking" : true,
        "rotate_urls_status" : false,
        "affiliate_url" : "www.google.com/[[subid]][[c1]][[c2]][[c3]][[c4]]"
    },
    {
        "payout" : 0.7,
        "landing_page" : [ ],
        "name" : "DOS",
        "rotate_urls" : null,
        "_module" : "setup.models",
        "_model" : "Campaigns",
        "cloaking" : true,
        "rotate_urls_status" : false,
        "affiliate_url" : "www.google.com/[[subid]][[c1]][[c2]][[c3]][[c4]]"
    }
],
"category_name" : "videos"}
```

I have tried for 8 days to append a new document inside "landing_page" which is in the collection with category_name equals to "videos" and which contains a campaigns document with name "DOS"
So, I'm trying to append a new document inside 
collection -> campaigns -> landin_page

I have tried using queries like this using django ORM:
affnetworkid = prepared django variable with the document id

```
collection = Categories.objects.get(id=affnetworkid,campaigns__in={name:campaign_name})
```

But nothing worked!! I need to return the categories result object which needs to have inside, this:

```
{
    "payout" : 0.7,
    "landing_page" : [ ],
    "name" : "DOS",
    "rotate_urls" : null,
    "_module" : "setup.models",
    "_model" : "Campaigns",
    "cloaking" : true,
    "rotate_urls_status" : false,
    "affiliate_url" : "www.google.com/[[subid]][[c1]][[c2]][[c3]][[c4]]"
}
```

So that way I can do this:

```
collection.landing_page.append(LandingPageClass)
collection.save()
```

But sadly until now, I have not been able to get the expected result... Can anyone give me a hand on this?
Also each time I try to iterate through a query like this:

```
a = Categories.objects.get(id=affnetworkid)
```

I receive an error saying that the returned object is not iterable.
Thanks